# Using two parameters (string, int) to define a max number of specific characters in string output

Tags: c#, count

I am not very experienced with C# and have got a task to develop a simple program that can take two parameters; one string and one integer. The string is to be returned, and the integer is supposed to define the max number of each specific character that is returned in the string, i.e.:

input: "aaabbbbc", "2" output: aabbc

input: "acc", "1" output: ac

I've tried looking at different collections like `IEnumerator` to help make the code easier to write, but as I'm not very experienced I can't sort out how to utilize them.

This is the code that I've written so far:

```
public static string TwoParameters()
{
    Console.Write("Write some characters (i.e. 'cccaabbb'): ");
    string myString = Console.ReadLine();
    return myString;
    Console.Write("Write a number - ");
    int max = Convert.ToInt32(Console.Read());
}

public static void Counter(string myString, int max)
{
    string myString = TwoParameters(myString);
    foreach (char a in myString)
    {
        var occurences = myString.Count(x => x == 'a');
        if (occurences > max)
            max = occurences;
    }
}
```

Errors I get when running:

> CS0136: Local or parameter 'myString' cannot be declared in scope because of enclosing local scope.
>
> CS1501: No overload for method 'TwoParameters' takes 1 arg.
>
> CS1061: 'string' does not contain a definition for count.
>
> CS0165: Use of unassigned local variable 'myString'.
>
> CS7036: There is no argument given that corresponds to the required formal parameter 'myString' of 'Program.Counter(string, int)'

Any kind of pointers to what I'm doing wrong, suggestions to how I can improve my code and/or finish it up for the program to make the output will be hugely appreciated.

Comment: Well, you've got 5 errors there - I suggest you focus on one at a time. Let's look at the first error first... do you understand what that's saying? You've got a parameter called `myString`, and you're trying to declare another local variable called `myString`. You can't do that. Perhaps you just want to assign a new value to the parameter instead?

Comment: divide and conquer: Create an empty StringBuilder. Iterate your input characterwise and count up to max. Add current character to Stringbuilder if < max && increase count for that letter. Next character check if equal to last one, if not reset counter to 0 else check/Add or skip, depending on if max is reached. Do until all characters are handled. This strategie handles _consecutive_ same letters, not overall occurence of letters. You can store your lettercount in a dictionary<char, int> if you need overall count.

Comment: is the maximum count of a character limited to a sequence or does it limit its occurence across the entire string (as in `abcabcabc 2` resulting in `abcabc` or `abcabcabc`)?

Comment: @MikeLimaSierra The integer is supposed to define occurence across the entire string. Your example will result in 'abcabc'.

Answer (score 3):

A string can be treated as an `IEnumerable<char>`. You can use LINQ to first group the characters then take only 2 from each group, eg :

```
var input="aaabbbbc";
var max=2;
var chars=input.GroupBy(c=>c)
               .SelectMany(g=>g.Take(2))
               .ToArray();
var result=new String(chars);
```

This produces

```
aabbc
```

This query groups the characters together with `GroupBy` and then takes only `max` from each group with `Take`. `SelectMany` flattens all the `IEnumerable<char>` returned from `Take` into a single `IEnumerable<char>` that can be used to create a string

Comment: Efkaresto! This was really helpful.

Answer (score 1):

This function would also respect the order within the string, so `aabcabc, 2` would result into `aabcbc`:

```
static string ReturnMaxOccurences(string source, int count)
{
    return source.Aggregate(new Accumulator(), (acc, c) =>
    {
        acc.Histogram.TryGetValue(c, out int charCount);

        if (charCount < count)
            acc.Result.Append(c);

        acc.Histogram[c] = ++charCount;

        return acc;
    }, acc => acc.Result.ToString());
}
```

But you need also this little helper class:

```
public class Accumulator
{
    public Dictionary<char, int> Histogram { get; } = new Dictionary<char, int>();
    public StringBuilder Result { get; } = new StringBuilder();

}
```

This method iterates the whole string and save within a histogram the occurences of each character. If the value is lower than the desired max value it will be added to the result string, otherwise it simply steps over the character and continues with the next.

Comment: Great, thank you! I actually don't think I specified that in my question, but I certainly needed it to respect the order. You've been very helpful!

Answer (score 0):

Pointers to what you are doing wrong:

- you reset your given max to the counts in your string
- you only handle "a"
- your `TwoParameters` function has unreachable code
- you try to declare a variable name again already providing it to the function as parameter
- you do not build a string to output

---

Using Linq is probably somewhat overkill for your level of knowledge. This is a simpler Version of [Oliver's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57923011/7505395) answer - respecting order of letters as well:

```
public static void Main()
{
    var input = "abbaaabcbcccd";
    var max = 2;

    // stores count of characters that we added already
    var occurences = new Dictionary<char,int>();

    var sb = new StringBuilder();
    foreach (var c in input)
    {
        // add with a count of 0 if not yet encountered
        if (!occurences.ContainsKey(c))
        {
            // if you want only "consecutive" letters not repeated over max:
            // uncomment the following line that resets your dict - you might
            // want to use a single integer and character instead in that case
            // occurences.Clear(); // better use a single int-counter instead
            occurences[c] = 0;
        }


        // add character if less then max occurences
        if (occurences[c] <  max)
        {
            sb.Append(c);           
            occurences[c]+=1;
        }
    }

    Console.WriteLine(sb.ToString());  
}
```

Output:

```
abbaccd
```

Comment: Thank you very much! A simple version should certainly fit my level of knowledge well.